# Multiple LEFT JOINS on the same table, using data from previous JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am using a LEFT JOIN in mysql to look up an organisation from a code which is in my dataset.

So the ***datatable*** might contain the *orgcode* **123**

Then the ***orgtable*** contains the *orgname* of the organisation ie 'The Local Bookstore'.

However the ***orgtable*** also contains another code which identifies the parent organisation of the 'The Local Bookstore', using another code ie **456**.

How do I write a query that goes to the ***orgtable***, looks up the *orgname*, also finds the *parentorgcode* and then looks that up in the same table to find the parent organisation name as well?

Basically using the output of one LEFT JOIN to generate another LEFT JOIN in the same query...

Thanks

Comment: can you show us some codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, if you are managing a hierarchy of data I highly recommend reading http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ as it will show you various methods to store it which may well allow you to use a more optimal method than you currently are.

Secondly, you can LEFT JOIN easily enough as you have asked but just need to make sure each new join uses an alias so that there is no ambiguity as to which field you request, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM datatable AS d
LEFT JOIN orgtable AS o1 ON o1.orgID = d.orgID
LEFT JOIN orgtable AS o2 ON o2.orgID = o1.parentOrgID
```

What you cannot do is automatically make MySQL keep adding on LEFT JOIN's until there is no parent. For that you will need either a recursive stored procedure, a looping stored procedure, or a nested tree (see link)

Comment: Just to add a thought, nested sets are great for reading trees, but have horrible performance on writing. So they are good for small trees or trees that virtually never change.

Comment: This is true, but the OP didn't really provide enough information to determine that.  In most cases I've seen where a tree of data is used, a nested set is a performance gain overall.  I guess the main example of where it wouldn't could be some kind of rapidly expanding pyramid scheme.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  Unfortunately, the data concerned I dont manage and I receive 'as is'.  I could change it into another format, which is what I would have tried next, but was hoping there was a query method.  The link you provide looks like it will be really helpful for another project, so thanks for that.   I did try using aliases but what was challenging me was what to match the data on as the new parent-org-code didnt exist (yet) in the data to match to.  I'll try what you describe in a bit - thanks for this

Comment: If the data doesn't exist then how do you expect to find it

Comment: Sorry, not being clear.  What I mean is - my first JOIN references the orgid in the datatable to match the orgid in the orgtable - LEFT JOIN ON datatable.orgid = orgtable.orgid.  But when I come to write another join, what is the match made on. because I don't have anything in the datatable to match to - so ?????? = orgtable.orgid.  The parent_org_id doesnt exist in the datatable.

Comment: If the first join, so `o1` to `d`, doesn't match a row, then the second join `o2` to `o1` will also not match any rows, and so on down the chain of joins.  You could as easily have given the query a try and seen what happens.

Comment: Thanks.  What I was missing was using an alias on BOTH joins so that I could reference the parent_org_id properly.  It's working now - thanks for your input

Comment: This is why you should post up the exact query you are trying to execute in these circumstances, as was requested by Ulfric.  If you had done that, then one of us would likely have spotted that right away and saved this fussing trying to guess at what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to use alias like this:

```
SELECT tb1.orgcode, tb2.orgcode
FROM orgtable AS tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN orgtable AS tb2 ON tb1.orgcode = tb2.orgcode
```

Comment: Thanks Ulfric.  Using the aliases on both JOINs was what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT O1.NAME AS ORG_NAME, O2.NAME AS PARENT_ORG_NAME
 FROM DATATABLE D
 JOIN ORGANISTION O1
 ON D.ORGID = O1.ORG_ID
 LEFT JOIN ORGANISTION O2
 ON O1.PARENT_ID = O2.ID
```